# willMoveToParentViewController and didMoveToParentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two view controllers, they are VCA and VCB. I also have a navigation controller and push from VCA to VCB. In the prepareForSegue method of VCA, I have the following line of code:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"placePiece"]) {
        NSLog(@"go to screen two");
    }
}
```

and in my VCB, I have the following two methods:

```
- (void) willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent {
    NSLog(@"will move back to screen one");
}

- (void) didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent {
    NSLog(@"did move back to screen one");
}
```

What I don't understand is when I go from VCA to VCB, I got the following message in the console:

```
2014-03-31 15:38:05.317 Li-Lab5[18865:60b] go to screen two
2014-03-31 15:38:05.318 Li-Lab5[18865:60b] will move back to screen one
2014-03-31 15:38:05.848 Li-Lab5[18865:60b] did move back to screen one
```

Why the `willMoveToParentViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController`method got called here?

Besides, is there a method for VCA and VCB such that when VCA go to VCB, a method in VCA got called. When VCB go back to VCA, a method in VCB got called. I just want to do some reading and writing in these methods. Thanks

Comment: Those two methods don't do what you think they do. The parent is not the viewController that initiated the push. The parent is the container view controller that holds that vc, in your case it's the navigationController.

Comment: so what can I do to achieve the effect I wanted?

Comment: You can use `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: @NobodyNada  is there a method that is guaranteed to be called when I go from VCB back to VCA?

Comment: @NobodyNada can you put the solution below so that I can mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a global `BOOL` variable in VCB's `viewWillDisappear:` to `YES`, and then in VCA's `viewWillAppear:`, if the variable is `YES` then you went from VCB to VCA.  Just be sure to set the variable back to `NO` in VCA's `viewDidAppear:`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by querying `[self isMovingToParentViewController]` in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`. If this returns `YES`, the view controller is appearing because it was pushed. If this returns `NO`, the view controller is appearing because the view controller above it was popped off the navigation stack (going back).

[The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW93) is confusing. While `isMovingToParentViewController` returns `YES` *only* when called from inside `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`, it may also return `NO` from inside these methods.

When the view is disappearing, you can query `[self isMovingFromParentViewController]` to obtain similar information.

This approach is more self contained than using global variables, so should lead to more reusable and maintainable code.